# Why my select only get the last value?

Tags: jquery

I want to get a `total` value of checkbox & select option.

The select option only work if I select the last value & the checkbox is working fine.

May I know what I'm doing wrong on select.

```
$(document).on('change keyup', '.price', function(){    
    var total_a = 0;
    var total_b = 0;
    var total_c = 0;    
    $('#total_a option').each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':selected')) {
            total_a = parseFloat($(this).attr("data-price"));
        } else {
            total_a = 0;
        }
    });    
    $('#total_b option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
            total_b = parseFloat($(this).attr("data-price"));
        } else {
            total_b = 0;
        }
    });    
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
        total_c += parseFloat($(this).attr("data-price"));
    });    
    $('.total').html('$ ' + (total_a + total_b + total_c).toFixed(2));    
});
```

Comment: Use `+=` shorthand in both `each`. `total_a += parseFloat($(this).attr("data-price"));`, `total_b += parseFloat($(this).attr("data-price"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just updating the variable value not adding them, also you can reduce your code by changing the selector

```js
$(document).on('change keyup', '.price', function() {
  var total_a = 0;
  var total_b = 0;
  var total_c = 0;
  $('#total_a option:selected').each(function() {
    total_a += parseFloat($(this).attr("data-price"));
  });
  $('#total_b option:selected').each(function() {
    total_b += parseFloat($(this).attr("data-price"));
  });
  $("input:checked").each(function() {
    total_c += parseFloat($(this).attr("data-price"));
  });
  $('.total').html('$ ' + (total_a + total_b + total_c).toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="total_a">
  <input class="price" type="checkbox" value=10 data-price="10" />
  <select class="price" multiple>
    <option value=10 data-price="10">10</option>
    <option value=20 data-price="20">20</option>
    <option value=111  data-price="111">111</option>
    <option value=210  data-price="210">210</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="total_b">
  <input type="checkbox" class="price" value=10 data-price="10"/>
  <select class="price" multiple>
    <option value=10 data-price="10">10</option>
    <option value=20 data-price="20">20</option>
    <option value=111  data-price="111">111</option>
    <option value=210  data-price="210">210</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="total"></div>
```

---

**UPDATE :** I n case if you don't want total value seperately then you can combine all each iterator

```js
$(document).on('change keyup', '.price', function() {
  var total = 0
  $('#total_a option:selected,#total_b option:selected,input:checked').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).attr("data-price"));
  });
  $('.total').html('$ ' + total.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="total_a">
  <input class="price" type="checkbox" value=10 data-price="10" />
  <select class="price" multiple>
    <option value=10 data-price="10">10</option>
    <option value=20 data-price="20">20</option>
    <option value=111 data-price="111">111</option>
    <option value=210 data-price="210">210</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="total_b">
  <input type="checkbox" class="price" value=10 data-price="10" />
  <select class="price" multiple>
    <option value=10 data-price="10">10</option>
    <option value=20 data-price="20">20</option>
    <option value=111 data-price="111">111</option>
    <option value=210 data-price="210">210</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="total"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're just changing the value each time but not adding to total. Do like this:

```
 total_a += parseFloat($(this).attr("data-price"));//total_a is added with this value
```

Instead of:

```
 total_a = parseFloat($(this).attr("data-price"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its simple to make it like this

```
$(document).on('change keyup', '.price', function() {

  var total = 0;
  $("#total_a option:selected ,#total_b option:selected , input:checked").each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).attr("data-price"));
  });

  $('.total').html('$ ' + (total).toFixed(2));

});
```